# How can I call element html by method vue?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

My vue component like this :

```
<template>
    ...
</template>

<script>

export default {
    methods: { 
        buildDescription () {
            if (!this.description) {
                const div = document.createElement('div')
                let html

                html = "..." /* call element html and store here */

                div.innerHTML = html
                document.querySelector('.v-date-picker-table').append(div)
                this.description = true
            }
        },
    }
}
</script>
```

See html variable. I want to call element html or a component from there

The element html like this :

```
<template>
    <div>
        <span>
            <div style='float:left; height: 14px; width: 14px; border-radius: 12px;'>
            </div>
        </span>
        <span style='float: left;font-size:12px'>Available</span>
        <span>
            <div style='float:left;height: 14px; width: 14px; border-radius: 12px;'>
            </div>
        </span>
        <span style='float:left; font-size: 12px'>Not available</span>
    </div>
</template>
```

How can I call the element html from method vue?

Comment: You have templates.  Use them.  Don't generate the html in your controller

Comment: Are you looking for [dynamic components](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html)?

Comment: @Taplar I custom datepicker vuetify. I need to add a description below datepicker. So I need to create a new element and append it like that

Comment: Which can be done in the template, with the template only adding the element when some `v-if` results in true

Comment: @Taplar It seems you don't know the vuetify datepicker. I need to call v-date-picker-table class. And it only called by javascript

Comment: Are you trying to modify the results of some external plugin's generated dom elements?

Comment: @Taplar I have not tried that. Mention some external plugins?

Comment: @SuccessMan - when you say "seems you don't know the vuetify datepicker." you possibly should mention what your actually trying to work with **in the question**

Comment: Perhaps you could show what you're trying to achieve visually

Answer (score 0):

DOM manipulation in Vue is no different than vanilla JavaScript. All the `document.getElement...` functions are fine.

However, as you saw in comments, the point of Vue is to write whatever manipulation you need in the template and use v-directives for DOM manipulation. There are very few cases in which you would need to still manipulate the DOM with vanilla JS. Consider why you're using a framework and how you can better accomplish what you need to within it.

Comment: I'm still confused. I need a spesific answer

Comment: The specific answer is to understand the point of using Vue or any framework, so I suggest watching the Intro to Vue series here: https://www.vuemastery.com/courses/intro-to-vue-js/vue-instance

Answer (score 0):

```js
export default {
    methods: { 
        buildDescription () {
            if (!this.description) {
                const div = document.createElement('div')
                **let html = this.$refs.myHtml.outerHTML**
                ...
            }
        },
    }
}
```

```html
<template>
    <div **ref="myHtml"**>
        <span>
            <div style='float:left; height: 14px; width: 14px; border-radius: 12px;'>
            </div>
        </span>
        <span style='float: left;font-size:12px'>Available</span>
        <span>
            <div style='float:left;height: 14px; width: 14px; border-radius: 12px;'>
            </div>
        </span>
        <span style='float:left; font-size: 12px'>Not available</span>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: You need to add ref to your hetml tag and then you can reach this html from the method by using "this.$refs"